# Passcode lock feature to prevent iPhone from being turned off

Tags: iphone

I have a teenage daughter who is making really poor decisions, I was able to keep track of her location until she learned to turn off her phone while she doesn't want to be found.  Has iPhone developed an app to install a passcode lock to prevent the phone from being turned off?

Comment: If you're ready to jailbreak the iPhone, I could give you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Although you've probably seen this page, [here are the restrictions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4213?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) you can enable on your daughter's iPhone. That's it.

Although I'm in no position to know exactly what is happening here, I *can* tell you that technology is not the answer.